Query Regarding File and Metadata Transfer via Microsoft Data Connect
Can we transfer actual files along with metadata from SharePoint to Azure via Microsoft Data Connect?
I understand that it is possible to transfer file information, but I couldn't find any reference indicating the transfer of actual files.
Please confirm if this is possible, and if yes, a reference link would be really helpful.
